# What happens with console.log statements in React Native apps from app stores?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, app-store

A React Native app I recently developed is now listed inside Google Play Store and iOS App Store. There is a problem that I want to debug now using log statements on my own iOS device. I prefixed the log statements for this functionality with a constant (e.g. a log message will be `[XYZ BLT] Started scanning for devices`) to make them searchable in a convenient way.
During the development I used to see the app logs on my iOS device using OSXs' console app. I just filtered all the phones logs by the prefix (`[XYC BLT]`).
Now with the app being installed from the App Store, this does not find log messages anymore, although I triggered them to be logged.

Are `console.log` calls from a React Native app from the App Store even creating real log entries? Should I log differently "in production"? Currently I am blind. How to approach this?